# Is the | pipe character making URLWithString: fail?

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

I have this very simple code:

```
PO(URLString);
url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
PO(url);
NSData * data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

(`PO()` is my macro to print stuff.)

It works most of the time. Here is the output:

> `2012-10-08 11:39:28.187 BadgerNew[2475:5007] <0x1f5321f0
>   BGCRBusinessForDisplay.m:(113)> URLString:
>   http://id.openrice.com/UserPhoto/photo/0/U/0005Z29E131A230CBA4A42n.jpg`
>
> `2012-10-08 11:39:28.193 BadgerNew[2475:5007] <0x1f5321f0
>   BGCRBusinessForDisplay.m:(115)> url:
>   http://id.openrice.com/UserPhoto/photo/0/U/0005Z29E131A230CBA4A42n.jpg`
>
> `2012-10-08 11:39:30.191 BadgerNew[2475:6b03] <0x1f529f00
>   BGCRBusinessForDisplay.m:(113)> URLString:
>   http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&zoom=16&size=160x160&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true&center=-6.187900,106.775429&markers=size:small|color:blue|-6.187900,106.775429`
>
> `2012-10-08 11:39:30.196 BadgerNew[2475:6b03] <0x1f529f00
>   BGCRBusinessForDisplay.m:(115)> url: (null)`

As you see, it works fine for http://id.openrice.com/UserPhoto/photo/0/U/0005Z29E131A230CBA4A42n.jpg and it fails on http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&zoom=16&size=160x160&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true&center=-6.187900,106.775429&markers=size:small|color:blue|-6.187900,106.775429

Perhaps the issue is the | in the Google URL. So what should I do with it?

Comment: You could use an URL shortener to make your URLs "valid" in the first place. I successfully used the [bit.ly developer API](http://dev.bitly.com/) to do this automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, the `|` (the "pipe") is the problem.

The [Apple docs for `URLWithString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-BAJBBDIB) say that the relevant external docs are RFCs [2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) and [1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt). According to them, `|` is an "unsafe" character and must always be encoded in a URL. The encoding for it is `%7C`.

You can correct the pipes in your string manually (if it is a hard-coded string), but the better solution would be to replace them and any other problematic characters using [`-[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a).

Comment: Your answer is more detailed than mine :)

Comment: So Josh's answer is even better if you do not want to use category.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own solution.

Yap the | is the problem.

So, I do:

```
    URLString = URLString.UTF8Encode;
```

UTF8Encode is defined in the following:

```
- (NSString *)UTF8Encode
{
    NSString* encodedstring = [self stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return encodedstring;
}
```

Yes, it's a category :D

Comment: If you really feel the need to wrap `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`, you should give that method a better name. You're not actually UTF-8 encoding it -- it's already UTF-8. Using the dot syntax for non-properties is also generally considered poor style.